# Why do I get this error when trying to run my Cordova application in Android?

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded and added "Nexus 5X API 26" to "Your Virtual Devices" in Android Studio, so that Cordova has at least 1 possible target to run in.

However, when I run the command

```
cordova run android
```

The terminal (after some other lines) responds:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.305 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
    /Users/karel/Cordova Projects/demo/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/karel/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator
Error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

The emulator runs fine when I run it from an application in Android Studio, but not when using the cordova run command - which does work for other platforms.

If you can help me, that would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try to target API 25 instead of 26.

Problem and his fix are reported here:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-android/93297/31

In file **/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js** line 202:

```
var num = target.split('(API level ')[1].replace(')', '');
```

You need to replaced it with a regex search and extraction:

```
var num = target.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

because the target is Android **API 26** and it is trying to parse it with this:

```
var num = target.split('(API level ')[1].replace(')', '')
```